# Derived (Calculated) Field From Another Model

Tags: python, sql-server, django

I have started a simple entry-level django project for practicing, it uses sql-server as the database (mssql-django).

How can I have a derived attribute (calculated column) from a different table as a field on my model?

Let's say I have this model

```
from django.db import models

class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    birth_date = models.DateField()

class JobTitles(models.Model):
    job_title = CharField(max_length=20)

class Jobs(models.Model):
    job_id = models.OneToOneField(
        JobTitles,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )
    person_id = models.ForeignKey(
        Person,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )
    job_income_in_usd = models.IntegerField()

class Salary(models.Model):
    person_id = models.ForeignKey(
        Person,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )
    name = 'SELECT name FROM Person WHERE Salary.person_id = Person.id'
    income_in_euro = 'SELECT job_income_in_usd * 0.89 FROM Jobs INNER JOIN Salary ON Salary.person_id=Jobs.person_id'
    age = 'SELECT datediff(year, (SELECT birth_date FROM Person WHERE Salary.person_id=Person.id), getdate())'
```

**How do I implement the above SELECT codes in Python-Django codes?**

Related questions:

[Derived attribute in Django model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20690804/derived-attribute-in-django-model)

[How to add a calculated field to a Django model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17682567/how-to-add-a-calculated-field-to-a-django-model)

[Django getting field names from different models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3839043/django-getting-field-names-from-different-models)

Related SQL-Server question:

[How to create derived attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49918232/how-to-create-derived-attribute)

Comment: Instead of a `raw sql` script, can you provide a pratical example of what you whant, with class and instance if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `@property` decorator for that, to give you an example:

```
class Salary(models.Model):
    person_id = models.ForeignKey(
        Person,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )
    
    @property
    def name(self):
        return self.person_id.name if self.person_id else None

    @property
    def income_in_euro(self):
        if not self.person_id:
           return
        return Jobs.objects.filter(person_id_id=self.person_id_id).first(). job_income_in_usd * 0.89
```

btw i do not think its a good idea naming your `ForeignKey`s with `_id` at the end.